# strcmp function doesn't work while comparing string and user input which includes Turkish characters

Tags: c, string, compare

```
char *x="Çankırı";
char *y=malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
scanf("%s",y);

if(strcmp(x,y) == 0)
    printf("A");
else
    printf("%s",y);
```

I enter 'Çankırı' for y, but else part runs. How can I compare these strings?

Windows10 , codeblocks.

EDIT: I found a clue. Problem is about setlocale function. When I use setlocale(LC_ALL,"TURKISH"), one of the string doesn't work fine(Output is not Çankırı, Ank2r2), and If I use setlocale(LC_ALL,"C"), other one doens't work fine. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This looks like a code page problem. What output do you get for `printf("%s" ,"Çankırı");`? What is your system?

Comment: BTW: `char *y=malloc(sizeof(char)*25);` is overkill, you can replace it with `char y[25]`.

Comment: Can't see turkish characters in output, output is like Ank2r2 . But printf("%s",y) 's output is Çankırı.   char y[25] didn't work but thanks for advice.

Comment: OK, thenit's not a C problem but a code page problem. What is your system? Windows, Linux, Mac,...?

Comment: Windows 10, I use CodeBlocks

Comment: Compile with all warnigns enabled, in Visual Studio I get this warning: `Warning C4566 character represented by universal - character - name '\u0131' cannot be represented in the current code page(1252)`

Comment: Only warning I get is ||WARNING: Can't read file's timestamp: C:\Users\x\Desktop\afcz\qdbmp.c|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136998/discussion-between-nerdic-sapo-and-michael-walz).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use functions that accept 'wide' characters.  For example:

```
#include <wchar.h>
wchar_t *x=L"Çankırı";
wchar_t y[25];
wscanf(L"%s",y);

if(wcscmp(x,y) == 0)
    wprintf(L"A");
else
    wprintf(L"%s",y);
```

Comment: Try again, my sample code was missing the required 'L' prefix for the wide-character strings.

Comment: ||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
|6|error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: That sounds like you need to use the `-finput-charset` argument to tell gcc which character set you're using.