# Can't read strings well because of encoding

Tags: c, string, compare

I asked this question first: [strcmp function doesn't work while comparing string and user input which includes Turkish characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542177/strcmp-function-doesnt-work-while-comparing-string-and-user-input-which-include)

but I found more specific problem. When I use setlocale(LC_ALL,"C"), I can get user inputs well, I mean without any character issue. But I can't get strings from text file well, they've been corrupted(example: Output is Y instead of Ş). If I set setlocale as LC_ALL,"turkish", then user's input corrupts. So, I can never compare two strings, because always one of them is wrong. How can I fix it?

I tried save file as UTF-8 and ANSI, didn't work.

OS: Windows10, IDE: CodeBlocks.

main function

```
    int i,j,x;
    char *target=malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
    char *source=malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
    printf("Source: ");
    scanf("%s",source);
    printf("%s",source);
    i=getID(source);
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "C" );
    printf("Target: ");
    scanf("%s",target);
    j=getID(target);
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "C" );
   printf("%s",source);//Works fine
```

Part of getID function:

```
    while(!feof(idList))
{
   /*Here reading strings line by line and spliting them.*/
    fgets(idListLine, 255, (FILE*)idList);
    char *tokenId = strtok(idListLine, s);
    j=0;
    while( tokenId != NULL )
    {
        idListStrings[j]=tokenId;
        j++;
        tokenId = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
    char *x=idListStrings[0];
    printf("%s",x); // Doesn't work fine

   setlocale(LC_ALL,"turkish");
    printf("||%s %s||\n\n",x,city);//x string works fine, city doesn't
    if(strcmp(x,city) == 0)//Never works because one of them is corrupted.
    {
        id=atoi(idListStrings[1]);
        break;
    }
}
fclose(idList);

return id;
```

Comment: Please post the related code.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I've just edited my post.